# Unable to open PDF documents in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using WebView to open a url which is in fact a pdf document. Here is the code snippet.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) context.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.stagecoachbus.com/PdfUploads/Timetable_28768_5.pdf");
```

And the error obtained is:

```
EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up
```

I was able to open normal web pages. However, opening pdf files results in exception.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the answers! Well, I decided to make the pdf document downloaded in the phone and open with generic pdf viewer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To open pdf in Webview , it better to show pdf via google doc service

```
WebView webView = (WebView) context.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.stagecoachbus.com/PdfUploads/Timetable_28768_5.pdf");
```

It help you to show pdf.

Comment: yeah, it will work. But wouldn't it work without google doc service?

Comment: To show pdf without google service > This post help you but you do not able to show in webview.>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728920/pdf-viewer-api-library-for-android-app-sample-code

Comment: Google docs approach doesn't seem to work for local PDF files, can you provide an example for local files?

Comment: The google docs suggestion is terrible. You have this google docs reader that's designed for desktop in a tiny screen. How is this considered a good solution? Are all of you purposely designing ugly apps? Not user friendly at all. This solution should be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to read pdf file offline

you can use [mupdf-android](https://mupdf.com/releases/index.html) library. it is good library.

I have used this in my one application. it is written in C. there instruction are given to make it workable.

Answer (score -1):

please check your size of file you are trying to preview as max file size limit is 25mb only.