# load content of pdf in Webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to display the content of a pdf file in a `WebView`.

**The problem:** 
When I start the `WebView` a new dialog is opening, whether I want load the pdf in Browser or in the pdf Viewer. But I want to load the content directly in the `WebView`. I tried it also with a prefix url to embed the content, but then it shows: no preview available.

**My Code:**

```
public class Changelog_View extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    String myPdfUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=DB700463EBEC6BC9&resid=DB700463EBEC6BC9%2120693&authkey=ALJ-NvyQqMdACpA&em=2";
    String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);


    setContentView(webview);
}
}
```

I tried it now with the android-pdfView library with this code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );

   com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView pdfView = new com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView ( getApplicationContext (), null );
    String myPdfUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=DB700463EBEC6BC9&resid=DB700463EBEC6BC9%2120693&authkey=ALJ-NvyQqMdACpA&em=2";

    pdfView.fromAsset(myPdfUrl)
            .defaultPage(1)
            .showMinimap(false)
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .onPageChange ( new OnPageChangeListener () {
                @Override
                public void onPageChanged ( int i, int i1 ) {

                }
            } )
            .load();
```

But then a `FileNotFoundException`appears at adress: `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=DB700463EBEC6BC9&resid=DB700463EBEC6BC9%2120693&authkey=ALJ-NvyQqMdACpA&em=2`. The adress refers directly to a pdf file from my onedrive account. So when I type in this link into a browser, the pdf file is downloading.

So how to display the pdf file from the adress: `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=DB700463EBEC6BC9&resid=DB700463EBEC6BC9%2120693&authkey=ALJ-NvyQqMdACpA&em=2` with the `android-pdfView` library in my application?

Thanks.

Comment: `WebView` has no means of displaying a PDF on its own.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Is there a possibility to Load any other file with formatted Text into a webview? Or do I have to use a library to do that?

Comment: You can get some help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803701/unable-to-open-pdf-documents-in-webview using google docs

Comment: "Is there a possibility to Load any other file with formatted Text into a webview?" -- `WebView` can display HTML. Many developers find that HTML is a reasonable format for formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

**To open pdf in Webview , it better to show pdf via google doc service**

```
WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_LINK);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no WebViewClient then its going to open in different window only.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```