# Opening a .pdf link in a Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a simple app with a webview.
Every time there is a PDF link on a page, after clicking it nothing happens. 
I am currently strangling with pdf links, they wont open no matter what. I tried some solutions but they just seam outdated.

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.bla;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://blabla.com");

    }


    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    }
```

Can you please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 8):

When you click a link to a .PDF the webview will try to download the file.  What you really want to do is open the file in an external browser session.  That will display the PDF, and also give you the choice to download it if you wish.  To do that, first set a download listener for your webview.

```
    //for download PDF files
    webView.setDownloadListener(new MyDownLoadListener());
```

Then, in the download listener, send the PDF link to an external browser session:

```
public class MyDownLoadListener implements DownloadListener {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

    if (url != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your method but it keeps giving me an error. Can you please edit the above code with this so that i can understand what am i implementing wrong? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it via Google doc service:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) context.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview? 
embedded=true&url=yourUrl");
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803701/unable-to-open-pdf-documents-in-webview)

Comment: Thank you for your method. The problem is that is a normal website that have some pdf links on it. So this isn't working, it opens website source. With single pdf ok but i need to kind of use it only when the user click a pdf link.